# How to group by date in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, json, react-native

I am trying to restructure my json response to order by date.

Here is the example Json I have:

```
"data": [
  {
    "game_id": "728721",
    "game_date": "2016-11-03 20:25:00",
  },
  {
    "game_id": "728722",
    "game_date": "2016-11-06 13:00:00",
  }
]
```

I want to display sections grouped by date in my listview.

Comment: What does this have to do with React native?  Sounds like you just want to transform the data structure.  If so, please provide an example of the data structure you would like to see

Comment: I am not sure if you want to group by (combine those who have the same date) or order by date (put them in chronological order, or the opposite for that matter).

Comment: Rob, here is the json structure am looking for:
Required json format
data = {
  "Date 1" : [
    {
      // Game data object 1
    },
    {
      // Game data object 2
    },
    {
      // Game data object 3
    },
    {
      // Game data object 4
    }],
  "Date 2" : [
    {
      // Game data object 5
    },
    {
      // Game data object 6
    },
    {
      // Game data object 7
    }]
};
 
Actual json format
data = [
 {
   // Game data object 1
 },
 {
   // Game data object 2
 },
 {
   // Game data object 3
 }
 ]

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript method without any library

Since your date time data contain actual string, one strait-forward could be split the string into date and time, then loop through each of item and group them according to date as key. Following is an example just to get the idea (I have not tested but it should work):

```
var groupData = (data) => {
    let result = []

    for (var d in data) {
        // get date from data
        var date = d.game_date.split(' ');

        // add into new array and use key as the date
        if (!result[date]) {
            result[date] = [d]
        } else {

            // if key already existed, extend into group
            result[date].push(d)
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this doesnt seem specific to React Native development. maybe try [lodash#groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#groupBy)

Comment: Hi Adam, 
look at this code, this is what I have but throwing an error:

 var grouped = _.groupBy(response.data.results.data, function(item) {
      console.tron.log(item.game_data)
      return item.game_date;
    });

Comment: Thank you for your reply. moment "groupBy" works. This is what I have done.
 var groupedByDate = _.groupBy(response.data.results.data, function(item) {
      var dateMoment = moment(item.game_date);
      return dateMoment.day(String).format('LL')
    });

Comment: nice! im glad that worked for you. checking lodash for solutions to problems usually is helpful for me.